# Duplicate PostgreSQL error code name 'string_data_right_truncation'

Tags: postgresql

I've been looking through [PostgreSQL error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html), and I've noticed that there are two error codes with the same name 'string_data_right_truncation'.

Once as a 'Warning', and once as a 'DataException'.

Do you know what the difference is?